# Adobe PDF simple Javascript loop not looping reliably

Tags: javascript, debugging, pdf, adobe

I have this loop that simply beeps every three seconds in a PDF document level script, for testing/debugging purposes:

```
// Beep every three seconds and write the current time in the document's text field named "FeedbackField

function testBeepAndUpdateField() { // beep and write current time in document text field
    app.beep();

    // Update the text field with the current time
    var now = new Date();
    var field = this.getField("FeedbackField");
    if (field) {
        field.value = "Updated at: " + now.toLocaleTimeString();
    }

    app.setTimeOut("testBeepAndUpdateField()", 3333); // function calls itself every 3333 milliseconds
}

app.setTimeOut("testBeepAndUpdateField()", 2000); // calls function and delays first auto-execution when opening the document by 2 seconds
```

For unknown reasons, it unpredictably loops zero to four times after the document is opened, and then stops.

[Here](https://community.adobe.com/havfw69955/attachments/havfw69955/acrobat/443060/2/PDF%20Layer%20Visibility%20Javascript%20Zoom%20Problem,%20Toggle%20Comments%20Layer.pdf) is a test document that contains the script and time display text field.

The issue only occurs in Adobe Acrobat or Reader, not in PDF-XChange Editor, for example.

Any workaround would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, will try in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC